# On a formula for Hypergeometric function $_3F_2(a,b,c;d,e;1)$

Tags: analysis, special-functions, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function

> I need  to prove a formula for the Hypergeometric function $_3F_2(a,b,c;d,e;1)$

I searched and got the following from Wolfram alpha ( see:- second formula in https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/03/02/01/)

The answer is something like $$_3F_2(a,b,c;d,e;1)=\frac{\sqrt{\Gamma(1-a)}  \sqrt{\Gamma(1-b)} \sqrt{\Gamma(1-c)} \Gamma(d)\Gamma(e)\sqrt{\Gamma(d+e-a-b-c)} <...>}{ \sqrt{\Gamma(d-a)}\sqrt{\Gamma(d-b)}\sqrt{\Gamma(d-c)} \sqrt{\Gamma(e-a)}\sqrt{\Gamma(e-b)} \sqrt{\Gamma(e-c)}  }$$ where $\Re(d+e-a-b-c)>0$

I am not able to understand that what is written in the given link in $<...>$. Also it would be really helpful if someone could prove this formula.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It’s a [Clebsch-Gordan coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients). Click on the arrow on your linked formula and you’ll see the Mathematica “input form” expression.

Comment: @Roman Thanks a lot. One more help please. Please tell me where can I find a proof of this formula.

Comment: This is not the right forum for math and proofs. Maybe you’ll have better luck at the math StackExchange.

Comment: I believe this is also known as Dixon’s identity.